Special Application of Rouché's Theorem
I have trouble with the following problem:
Let $P(z) = z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots +a_0$ and $|P(z)| \leq 1$ if $|z|=1$.
Prove that $P(z)=z^n$.
If one tries to apply Rouché's theorem, first look at $g(z)=-z^n$. Then, of course, $|g(z)|=1$ on the unit circle. If $|P(z)| \lt 1$, then $n = |- z^n|_0 = |P(z) - z^n|_0$ by Rouché, and $a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots +a_0 = 0$ because of the fundamental theorem of algebra.
But now we know that $|tP(z) - g(z)|_0$ with $0 \leq t \lt 1$. I have been trying to apply Rouché's theorem a second time, maybe on another disk.
My Attempt (which is not correct)
Since $|tP(z) - g(z)|_0 = n$ on the unit circle (and everywhere else), we choose $t=\frac{1}{2}$.
So
$$\tilde{P}(z) = \frac{1}{2}P-z^n
=\frac{-z^n}{2}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{2}z^{n-1} + \ldots + \frac{a_0}{2}$$
If we multiply the term, the zeros wont change, so $$2\tilde{P}(z)=-z^n + P(z) - z^n$$
Now, we apply Rouché's theorem: $|2\tilde{P}| \gt |P|$, so $$n = |2\tilde{P}(z)|_0 = |2\tilde{P}(z) + P(z)|_0 = |2(P(z)-z^n)|_0$$
Finally, the $2(P(z)-z^n)$ should have the same zeros as $(P(z)-z^n)$, which was a polynomial of grade $n-1$. But we know that it has $n$ zeros, so because of the fundamental theorem of algebra, it is constant. Therefore zero.
-> There are 2 Erros: firstly: $|2\tilde{P}| \gt |P|$ looks nice but is a baseless claim. secondly, the conclusion. Because Rouche, $(P(z)-z^n)$ should have exactly $n$ zeros, which is just a contradiction

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

something is off in your approach -- if you are able to apply Rouche then $2(P(z)-z^n)$ has exactly $n$ zeros so it cannot be  constant

my inequality $|2\tilde{P}| \gt |P|$ simply didnt hold

I suggest observing that if $P(z)\neq z^n$ then say for $z\in \partial B\big(0,2\big)$
$\vert - z^n\vert \gt \vert P(z)\vert\implies \Big(-z^n + P(z)\Big)$ has degree at most $n-1$ and exactly $n$ roots in $B\big(0,2\big)$ per Rouche which is impossible.
The inequality is Suppose $P(z) = a_0+a_1z + \dots + a_nz^n$ is bounded by 1 for $|z|\leq 1$. Show that $|P(z)|\leq |z^n|$ for all $|z^n|\geq 1$

i dont quite follow your proof. is $|-z^n|>|P(z)|$ prooven in the link? There, $P(z)$ is bounded by $1$ per definition, which is not the case here

Your comment "There, () is bounded by 1 per definition, which is not the case here" does not make sense.  Please carefully re-read the problem and answers in the link.  In the link and this problem we are talking about a degree at most $n$ polynomial that has modulus $\leq 1$ for $z \in\overline B(0,1)$.  The link then tells you that $\vert P(z)\vert \leq \vert z\vert^n$ for $\vert z\vert \gt 1$ and the inequality is strict if $P(z)\not\propto z^n$.  I proved the result using Rouche; you'll see another answer using $ z^n P(1/z)$ so there are common proof techniques to this page.

so the linked inequality is: w/ degree at most $n$, if $P(z)$ has modulus at most 1 in the $\overline B(0,1)$ then $\vert P(z)\vert \leq \vert z^n\vert $ for all $z \in \mathbb C-\overline B(0,1)$ and the inequality is strict everywhere- unless $P(z)=\alpha z^n$ for some $\alpha\in S^1$.  I show this in the comment to my post in the link; the strictness conditions may be easier to understand via the max modulus in Conrad's answer though I appreciate the enthusiasm for Rouche.  Now for this page: in your OP we know that $P(z)$ is monic so $\alpha =1$ is the only case to consider.

i liked your proof because one applies Rouche twice - earlier in the contradiction for the inequalitiy - ill streamline it and add it to the question when i find the time

The linked inequality is of considerable independent interest so I would not recommend any combining.  Note: the 3rd response in the link used Parseval; you can do a 1 line proof to your question here by direct application of Parseval.  So all 3 proof techniques there apply here though Parseval will be the quickest (try it).  Also when you ask a question it in the comments and I answer it and you then delete the question afterwards... it makes these comments very hard to follow for 3rd parties.

i deleted the question because i saw the answer myself, i didnt realize you replied

I am not really sure how to apply Rouche's theorem here, but below I give a simple proof via maximum modulus principle.
Consider another polynomial $Q(z) = 1 + a_{n-1}z + a_{n-2}z^2 + \dots a_{0}z^n$. Clearly, for $z \ne 0$ we have $Q(z) = z^n P(1/z)$. On the unit circle $Q$ inherits the property $|Q(z)| \le 1$ from $P$. But, clearly, $Q(0) = 1$. Thus, by the maximum modulus principle $Q$ is constant, hence, $Q \equiv 1$ and $P(z) = z^n$.

nice, ill add my solution using  Rouché into the Question
